# How to decouple nested object functions within a class

Tags: javascript, node.js, prototype

### Background

This is a simplified example that demonstrates what I'm trying to accomplish. I am attempting to create a class `Person(name)`. This class has an object `say` that has several functions associated with it, e.g.

```js
Person.say.name();
```

When invoked, this should output `My name is (name provided)`

### Simple Working Example

```js
// node v0.10.15
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
};

Person.prototype.say = function() {
    var self = this;
    this.say = {
        name: function() {
            console.log('My name is ' + self.name);
        }
    };
};

Person.prototype.say();

var p = new Person('Nolan');
p.greet();
p.say.name();
```

The above will output

```
Hello Nolan 
My name is undefined
```

### What I've tried

I've tried using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```js
Person.prototype.say = function() {
    var name = function() {
        console.log('My name is ' + this.name);
    };
    this.say = {};
    this.say.name = name.bind(this);
};
```

I've also tried using [defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) in the Person function:

```js
var Person = function(name) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
        get: function() { return name; }
    });
};
```

But the output remains the same.

### What works

What *does* work is nesting the `say` object inside of the Person function:

```js
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    var self = this;
    this.say = {
        name: function() {
            console.log('My name is ' + self.name);
        }
    };
};
```

But this is what I'm trying to avoid, as the `say` object may house several more functions besides `name()` (e.g. age, email, and so on) and the main Person function will get bloated.

### The Question

How can I decouple the `say` object from the main Person function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your first approach isn't working is because when you call:
`x.say()`, inside the body of `say` `this` will refer to `x`.

When you call:
`x.say.name()`, inside the body of `name`, `this` will refer to `x.say`.

In order for `x.say.name()` to give the correct answer, `x.say` should have a reference to `x`. So, in your constructor you need to link the `say` object with your new instance (that is why the nested thing works).

A better separation can be done like this:

```
Sayer = function(person){
  this.person = person;
};
Sayer.prototype.name = function() {
    console.log('My name is ' + this.person.name);    
};

var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.say = new Sayer(this);
};

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
};

p = new Person('George');
p.say.name();
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/OPuveGA/1/edit

PS: Obviously, you can define the Sayer constructor in any namespace you want, including Person, so you can have `this.say = new Person.Sayer(this)` in your Person constructor - check the demo above.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this what you had in mind:

```
// node v0.10.15
var Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.say = new Person.prototype.say(name);
};

Person.prototype.greet = function() {
    console.log('Hello ' + this.name);
};

Person.prototype.say = function(moniker) {
    this.moniker = moniker;
    this.name =  function() {
            console.log('My name is ' + moniker);
        };
};

Person.prototype.say();

var p = new Person('Nolan');
p.greet();
p.say.name();
```

Comment: This is no good, each Person instance will have their own property say and functions defined on this property are not shared. So this would be the same thing as the code that already works.